# HTML not showing emoji data

Tags: html, reactjs, unicode

I'm not sure how face this question, I'm working on a React web, using [React-Select](https://react-select.com/), but I think my problem is not related to any of those libraries but it's some html, unicode, thing.

I have a `data` file where I store in a JSON object some string values and emoji data. In the IDE I can't see the value of those emojis, but it looks like this:

[image]

When I use in a React native mobile app those emojis, they work ok, and I can see them, but not in web, I just get this rendered:

[image]

So, how could I use those emojis from the `data` file in a web app?

Answer (score 0):

Set UTF-8 encoding in your IDE.

Comment: Ok, but what about the web? there's is where I want to see the emojis